# MySQL server won't accept remote connections

Tags: networking, mysql

I have a server (CentOS 7) running a fresh install of MySQL server (14.14 Distrib 5.6.51) with a dummy database, and I can't connect to it from a remote computer (both remote server and local computer within a VPN). I get the error "Connection Refused (111).

**I can**, however, connect from within the server and from remote computers in the VPN **using an ssh tunnel**. Sadly, I can't use SSH tunnels for prod and I *really* need this server to allow remote connections.

**So far, I have:**

- [Granted remote access to my user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLbUa.png)
- [Set bind-address to 0.0.0.0 (and the IP adress of the server, and commeting the line) in te my.cnf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eakX3.png)
- [Set skip_networking to off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWxZR.png)
- [Made sure default port was in use and bound address was 0.0.0.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP5xq.png)
- [Allowed 3306 to listen from anywhere with `ufw`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLMq3.png)

The output from ss looks as follows:

```
$$ ss -lnpt
State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port               Peer Address:Port

LISTEN     0      128          *:4000                     *:*
LISTEN     0      80           *:3306                     *:*
LISTEN     0      128          *:11211                    *:*
LISTEN     0      128          *:22                       *:*
LISTEN     0      128       [::]:22                    [::]:*
```

I'm completely out of ideas. What am I missing?

Comment: Note that in many cloud environments,  in addition to a host based firewall (the iptables rules you manage with ufw) there will be a firewall / network access list / security policy managed outside of the instance itself. That can also be the reason specific ingress/egress traffic is blocked. Also what is the error message when you attempt to make a remote MySQL connection? Is it a network error or a MySQL protocol message ?

Comment: Good question, I get a "Connection refused (111)" error. I'll update the question accordingly. What you mention about the cloud environments might be a thing. I'll investigate, thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `ss -lnpt`?

Comment: added the ss output to the question. Thanks. Didn't know this tool. What does this output mean?

Comment: There is "something" (most likely your mysql) listening on *:3306. Make *absolutely* sure, there isn't *any* firewall between your client and the server (aka 'on' the client an/or server) and that you are using correct adress (like not using the servers WAN IP when connection through VPN with a VPN-Only route). Also, make sure your VPN isn't blocking anything.